# Play gif only when it enters viewport from top or bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to play a gif onscroll only when it enters in the viewport either from top or bottom otherwise to show a static image. This is the code I've got so far, but it doesn't show the gif.  I am using https://github.com/rubentd/gifplayer and https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible to try to achieve this result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html,body{
            height:100%;
            margin:0;
            padding:0
        }
        body:before{
            content:"";
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:block;
        }
        body:after{
            content:"";
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rubentd.com/bower_components/jquery.gifplayer/dist/gifplayer.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rubentd.com/bower_components/jquery.gifplayer/dist/jquery.gifplayer.js"></script>
    <script src="http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/jquery.visible.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <h2>Play within view only:</h2>
        <img id="element" class="gifplayer" src="http://rubentd.com/img/banana.png" />
    </section>

    <script>
        $('#element').visible( function(){
            $('.gifplayer').gifplayer();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Switching $(document).ready( function(){
            $('.gifplayer').gifplayer();
        });
Plays the gif on click, but as mentioned, I want it to play on scroll when in comes in the viewport.

Comment: `visible` is a jQuery selector not a function. also where are you referencing the .gif file  ( i am not sure how that library works)

Comment: the gifplayer automatically pulls the gif file, with same naming as the jpg file. Do you know how to enable this onscroll when it comes within viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution doesn't work because this `visible` function doesn't accept any callback.

This is working example. You had to add scroll event listener and play or stop gif programmatically:

CSS (necessary, gifplayer adds `position: absolute`):

```
.gif {
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML (added container, because of above):

```
<div class="gif">
    <img id="element" class="gifplayer" src="http://rubentd.com/img/banana.png" />
</div>
<div class="gif">
    <img id="element" class="gifplayer" src="http://rubentd.com/img/banana.png" />
</div>
<div class="gif">
    <img id="element" class="gifplayer" src="http://rubentd.com/img/banana.png" />
</div>
```

JS, working scroll event listener with play or stop logic:

```
$('.gifplayer');
$('.gifplayer').gifplayer();

$gifs = $('.gif');

$gifs.each(function (i, gif) {
    $(gif).data('isPlaying', false);
});


$(window).scroll(function () {
    $gifs = $('.gif');

    $gifs.each(function (i, gif) {
        $gif = $(gif);

        if ($gif.visible(true)) {
            if (!$gif.data('isPlaying')) {
                $gif.find('.gifplayer').gifplayer('play');
                $gif.data('isPlaying', true);
            }

            if ($gif.find('.gp-gif-element').length > 1) {
                $gif.find('.gp-gif-element').first().remove();
            }
        } else {
            if ($gif.data('isPlaying')) {
                $gif.find('.gifplayer').gifplayer('stop');
                $gif.data('isPlaying', false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works flawlessly! Is it possible to make the gif play from the beginning everytime it enters the viewport? I also noticed in the console log that it adds a new gif everytime it becomes visible.

Comment: @Nikkd Yes, you have to pass `true` value to visible function: `if ($('.gif').visible(true)) {`.

Comment: @Nikkd I don't know why this script adds a new gif, when `play` is called.

Comment: it seems that does not reset the gif, I just implemented it, and it still just plays the gif once and does not reset it from the beginning when scrolling in and out of view

Comment: I greatly appreciate your quick responses!

Comment: @Nikkd I modified my solution. Now this works for many gifs. I try remove that unnecessary gifs.

Comment: Yes this works now to removing the unnecessary gifs, but once the gif is activated, it does not switch back to the jpg when you scroll it out of view and then back in view, and it does not reset the gif. Are you also experiencing this? I am trying to modify your code but haven't had much luck.

Comment: @Nikkd When? When you click on gif and then scroll?

Comment: I would like it to switch from jpg to gif and then back to jpg based on scroll only when it comes into view it's a gif and when it leaves viewport it's a jpg, not having to click to stop it.

Comment: @Nikkd Hmm, works fine, as you want. Are you sure you copied everything from my answer? I modified my answer several times. Maybe you have a slightly outdated version.

Comment: If you view the console log, you will see that the .gif does not get replaced when scrolled out of view, and if you have a gif that does not loop like the example used, it will not start from the beginning. it will just play once and stop, this is the issue I am having with this

Comment: No worries, I will try my best to solve for it if I am able to. I really appreciate your great help and quick responses Dawid!

Answer (score 0):

jquery-visible simply checks if the element is visible at the time `.visible()` is called. It doesn't alert you or run code when something *becomes* visible. You could potentially make a scroll event listener that calls `.visible()` on each scroll and if it returns `true` you could run your gifplayer code. Or you could use a plugin such as [Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints), which is designed to run code when something *becomes* visible.